# Lucky thumbtack

Tags: lateral-thinking

You have a lucky thumbtack and a pencil in your pocket at an amusement park and you want to ride a roller coaster. How do you make sure not to lose your lucky thumbtack on the ride, without holding either the pencil or the thumbtack in your hand or mouth?

Comment: Or you could just just sit on the thumbtack!

Answer (score 8):

You could:

> Leave the pencil inside your pocket. Push the thumbtack from the outside, through the fabric, into the pencil. Both will be held in place, leaving your hands free.

Comment: You can’t hold the pencil either, as you want to wave your hands around on the ride

Comment: Correct, or through your pocket

Comment: This answer is definitely correct (and very likely intended), but I wonder if there are more outside the box answers that could also be correct?

Answer (score 5):

> Leave it with someone you trust. Even if they are taking the ride with you, they can hold the stuff in their hands (it is mentioned that the rule applies to *you*).

Comment: Wouldn't this be bad luck? It's a lucky thumbtack, after all :)

Answer (score 4):

I know that the intended answer was already posted, but I still want to post this for sharing

> Ignore the pencil, take off your shoe, pin the thumbtack into your sole/ insole, put on your shoe. You may feel uncomfortable, but at least your thumbtack is safe.

Answer (score 2):

You should:

> eat them both, in any order.

Comment: Don't eat thumbtacks, kids.